# Why is http request with '&&&' is blocked

Tags: spring, http, tomcat, servlets

I have a web app on testing and production servers. on the prod server when I send a POST request with payload containing '&&&', my request is blocked and return no http status. The request passed successfully on the testing server. 
What could be blocking the request on the production server ? firewall ? issue with tomcat configuration ? Does &&& have any special meaning ?

I am using spring, tomcat 7

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does the request contains &&& mean? A request can be composed of many parts.

Comment: See updated content. Thanks

Comment: Well if you are sending that as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then it is invalid request. And since that is being parsed by servlet container (into `request.parameters`) it will not reach your servlet.

Comment: Why ? Why does '&&' passes successfully and not '&&&' ?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting a 400 response with an empty body?

Comment: It seems that an exception the server(tomcat 7) and/or the framework(spring) didn't expect occurs, while the server-side web application is parsing the payload, before sending a response to the client. You should check the log on the server.